# DeepLearning4J - Acquiring Data and Train Model

Tags: neural-network, deeplearning4j, data-acquisition

I try to create the easiest of a NeuralNetwork and training it with some data:
Therefore I created a test.csv with a the following pattern:

> number,number+1;
>
> number2,number2+1

...

I try to make a linear regression with the network...

But I do not find a way to acquire the data, DataSetIterator does not work.

How to fit the Data, how to test the Data?

Comment: Can you show us the code you put together so far? What do you mean by "DataSetIterator does not work"?

Answer (score 0):

In our examples, we encourage people to use datavec + recordreaderdatasetiterator.

Datavec has all of the various  data loading components.
I'm not sure what you mean about  "datasetiterator not working" wihtout seeing any code, but it seems like you didn't really look at our examples.

In there are multiple examples of a csv record reader you can use for both regression and classification use cases.
Consider reorienting your data pipeline to use those.
Those examples are always found here:
https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples

If you follow any of those, the same pattern emerges:
Record reader for whatever data format -> RecordReaderDataSetIterator

The iterator allows you to specify common constructors such as whether it is a regression or not, which column your label is etc.